# How to add columns and rows of a dataframe as keys and values of a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dataframe with two columns and what i basically want to do is to make a dictionary with the column names as key and concatenated rows for that column as values.

Here is an example dataframe that contains 2 columns

```
X1KS_AH353KBBXX_8_Aspen_F07_X5  X2861_AH353KBBXX_8_Aspen_D08_X5
G   G
N   C
G   G
M   C
G   G
A   A
```

I was able to do this for 1 column but how do i make for two columns. I tried looping as well as making a function and then looping them but none of them worked

```
import re
file_in = open("HapMap.filtered.hmp_test.txt")

result = {}
for line in file_in:
    line = line.strip().split()
    line2 = line[1]
    if re.search("Aspen", line2):
        gene = line2
        result[gene] = ""
    else:
        result[gene]+=line2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, you want to make your dataframe into a dictionary, with the column name as the key and the values in that column presented as a list?

If so, I suggest using the pandas module.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')#a csv file with data just how you presented it above.
dataDict = pd.DataFrame.to_dict(df, orient='list')#turns the dataframe into a dictionary, with the values presented as a list for each column.

print (dataDict)
```

This is the output:

```
{'X2861_AH353KBBXX_8_Aspen_D08_X5': ['G', 'C', 'G', 'C', 'G', 'A'], 'X1KS_AH353KBBXX_8_Aspen_F07_X5': ['G', 'N', 'G', 'M', 'G', 'A']}
```

Comment: Very elegant and easy solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
import re
file_in = open("HapMap.filtered.hmp_test.txt")

columns = 2
result = {}

for line in file_in:
    line = line.strip().split()
    for column in range(columns):
        line2 = line[column]
        if re.search("Aspen", line2):
            gene = line2
            result[gene] = ""
        else:
            result[gene]+=line2
```

This repeats your code for every column.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting challenge that deserves a generic solution. I interpreted the requirement as the values being a concatenated string.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import collections as cols
text="""col1 col2 col3
a 1 &
b 2 @
c 3 $
"""
d = cols.OrderedDict()
h = text.splitlines()[0].split(" ") # headers
cH = len(h)
c = 0
for line in text.splitlines():
    for item in line.split(" "):
        if c >= cH: # lines greater than first, the headers, the dict keys
            mod = c % cH
            try:
                d[h[mod]] = d[h[mod]] + item
            except KeyError: # will happen only on first item
                d[h[mod]] = item
        c += 1
print(d)
```

Result:

```
OrderedDict([('col1', 'abc'), ('col2', '123'), ('col3', '&@$')])
```

The OrderedDict will be ordered as the input. If you prefer the regular unordered dictionary, use the `dict()` constructor instead of `OrderedDict()` from the `collections` module.